# How to create a nsdictionary singleton value

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I'm having issues with dictionary, i want a dictionary create only once to save data to plist file. So how to create singleton dictionary ? Thank in advance

Comment: Do you need this dictionary to be a global constant or a class method?

Comment: i need global constant

Comment: create a singleton class and just declare NSDictionary over there..and you can get their value anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one instance of NSDictionary in `AppDelegate`, make this dictionary as a public property of class.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *myDict;
```

Initialize this in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

Now access it through out the app -

```
((AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).myDict
```

Only one instance will be created for your use.

Answer (score 0):

As you responded in comments, you need a global variable. Bellow is the receipt.

**Here is what you can do:**

1. Add variable extern definition at the top of your `AppDelegate.h` file:

   extern NSMutableDictionary *MyGlobalDictionary;
2. Add variable definition at the top of your `AppDelegate.m` file:

   NSMutableDictionary *MyGlobalDictionary;
3. Now you need to initialize the dictionary, can be done in `initialize` method of you `AppDelegate`. In AppDelegate.m add this somewhere in `@implemetaion` of `AppDelegate`:

   `+ (void)initialize {
       MyGlobalDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   }`

**How to use:**

Whenever you need it, just `#import` your `AppDelegate.h` file. Bellow is an example how to use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [MyGlobalDictionary objectForKey:@"someKey"]);
```

**Important:**

While creating singleton is extremely easy it is considered to be a bad practice. Think about passing your dictionary to objects that can be interested in it. Or may be define some global class singleton if it is unavoidable.